# validate field after setting value via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, validation

I have asp net MVC project. And I have form with few inputs in view. For client side validation I use two libraries:

***jquery.validate.js*** and ***jquery.validate.unbrostive.js***

For example I have field email:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "required" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", @autocomplete = "nope" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Email)
</div>
```

If I press "submit" button with empty field , it shows me an error "Email field required"

Ok. If after message has been shown I put value in field via jQuery, like this:

```
$("#Email").val("some@email.com");
```

The error message still shows unlike if I type text the error dissaperes. I tried to manualy trigger validation, but the error still shows:

```
$("#Email").val("some@email.com"); 
$("#cartForm").validate();
```

Strange thing that after updating value via jQuery the can be submited even error shows.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `$('form').validate().form();` to manually trigger the validation to re-run.
Call this **AFTER** setting the input field to a valid value, like this:

```
$("#validInput").click(function () {

    $("#UserName").val("user@company.com");

    $('form').validate().form();

});
```

Comment: this helped me. Thanks